# jaas basic authentication jetty-runner

Tags: docker, jaas, jetty-9

I am trying to get jaas basic authentication working witha webapp run with jetty runner, but I am having no luck, even with the most basic webapp.

I am following the instructions [here](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jaas-support.html)

Firstly I generate a brand new webapp project using

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp
```

the generated web.xml is as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

I run mvn package, then using jetty-runner 9.2.5.v20141112 I execute jetty-runner with the war

```
 java -jar jetty-runner.jar testwebapp.war
```

navigating to localhost:8080 using chrome browser I see the "Hello World!" message

I stop jetty-runner and edit the web.xml to add the login configuration details so that it looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

<login-config>
  <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
  <realm-name>Test JAAS Realm</realm-name>
</login-config>

</web-app>
```

I run mvn package

Then I create a jetty configuration file called **myjass.xml** as below

```
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">

  <Call name="addBean">
    <Arg>
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.jaas.JAASLoginService">
        <Set name="name">Test JAAS Realm</Set>
        <Set name="LoginModuleName">mysecurity</Set>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </Call>

</Configure>
```

I create a configuration file for the security called **mysecurity.conf**, as below

```
mysecurity {
        org.eclipse.jetty.jaas.spi.PropertyFileLoginModule required
        debug="true"
        file="security.props";
      };
```

finally I create the **security.props** file simply containing

```
test: Password_123
```

all these files are in the same directory as jetty-runner.jar, I then run

```
java -Djava.security.auth.login.config=mysecurity.conf -jar jetty-runner.jar --config myjass.xml testwebapp.war
```

There are no exceptions. When I navigate to loclhost:8080 I was fully expecting to be asked for my credentials, but instead it simply displayed the HelloWorld message as before. Am I misunderstanding something fundemental regarding the jass authentication in jetty?

**Update 2017-04-27.**

Following Walkerwatch's comment I tried again just using a standard distribution. I created a docker image called *jetty-test* from the following Dockerfile, which builds with jetty 9.4.4.v20170414

```
FROM jetty

RUN java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar --add-to-start=jaas

RUN echo "jetty.jaas.login.conf=$JETTY_BASE/etc/login.conf" >> $JETTY_BASE/start.d/jaas.ini

COPY mysecurity.conf $JETTY_BASE/etc/login.conf 
COPY security.props $JETTY_BASE/etc/security.props
COPY context.xml $JETTY_BASE/webapps/context.xml
COPY jetty-test.war $JETTY_BASE/jetty-test.war
```

the files are as follows

**mysecurity.conf**

```
mysecurity {
        org.eclipse.jetty.jaas.spi.PropertyFileLoginModule required
        debug="true"
        file="/var/lib/jetty/etc/security.props";
      };
```

**security.props**

```
test: Password_123
```

**context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_3.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">

  <Set name="contextPath">/doesthiswork</Set>
  <Set name="war">/var/lib/jetty/jetty-test.war</Set>

  <Set name="securityHandler">
    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler">
     <Set name="loginService">
       <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.jaas.JAASLoginService">
         <Set name="name">Test JAAS Realm</Set>
         <Set name="loginModuleName">mysecurity</Set>
       </New>
     </Set>
    </New>
  </Set>

</Configure>
```

the jety-test.war was built as described previously, but with

**web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Test JAAS Realm</realm-name>
  </login-config>

</web-app>
```

When I start the docker container with

```
docker run  -d -p8080:8080 --name=jetty-test -t jetty-test
```

I can navigate to localhost:8080/doesthiswork and the page loads without asking for any credentials. If I start with debug switched on, I see in the logs

```
2017-04-27 15:49:24.565:DBUG:oejx.XmlParser:main: parse: file:/usr/local/jetty/etc/jetty-jaas.xml

2017-04-27 15:49:24.566:DBUG:oejx.XmlParser:main: parsing: sid=file:/usr/local/jetty/etc/jetty-jaas.xml,pid=null
```

and

```
2017-04-27 15:49:24.669:DBUG:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: XML new org.eclipse.jetty.jaas.JAASLoginService

2017-04-27 15:49:24.670:DBUG:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: using normal mapping

2017-04-27 15:49:24.670:DBUG:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: XML org.eclipse.jetty.jaas.JAASLoginService@578486a3.setName(Test JAAS Realm)

2017-04-27 15:49:24.671:DBUG:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: XML org.eclipse.jetty.jaas.JAASLoginService@578486a3.setLoginModuleName(mysecurity)

2017-04-27 15:49:24.671:DBUG:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: XML org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler@5bc79255.setLoginService(org.eclipse.jetty.jaas.JAASLoginService@578486a3)

2017-04-27 15:49:24.673:DBUG:oejuc.ContainerLifeCycle:main: org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler@5bc79255 added {org.eclipse.jetty.jaas.JAASLoginService@578486a3,AUTO}

2017-04-27 15:49:24.673:DBUG:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: XML o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@4e9ba398{/doesthiswork,null,UNAVAILABLE}{/var/lib/jetty/jetty-test.war}.setSecurityHandle
```

and

```
2017-04-27 15:49:25.091:DBUG:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:main: starting org.eclipse.jetty.jaas.JAASLoginService@578486a3

2017-04-27 15:49:25.091:DBUG:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:main: STARTED @1201ms org.eclipse.jetty.jaas.JAASLoginService@578486a3
```

so it seems that the jaas service starts OK, but I am never asked for any credentials. What is it that I am missing/misunderstanding?

Comment: Jetty runner is an advanced usage method for running webapps. I'd recommend trying to get this working in a standard distribution before trying to build from scratch on runner. Also, unless you are forced into using an older version of Jetty, I'd highly recommend upgrading to the newest version (9.4.4 as of this writing). Finally, I'd recommend using servlet 3.1 as 2.3 is now 16 years old.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer myself. I was simply being stupid, and had not included any security constraints to my web app. So there were no resources that were marked as requiring authentication. Adding the below to the web.xml resolved the issue

```
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Everything</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
    <role-name>**</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```